# Transforming a two-variable std::function to a single-variable one

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a function which gets two values, x and y, and returns the result:

```
std::function< double( double, double ) > mult = 
  []( double x, double y){ return x*y; };
```

Now I want to get a single-variable function for a constant y. I have written the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
std::function<
  std::function< double(double) > (
    std::function< double(double, double) >,
    double
  )
> funcYgivenX =
  [](std::function< double(double, double) > func2d, double inX) {
    return [&func2d, &inX]( double inY ) {
      return func2d(inX, inY);
    };
  };
```

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the best (most efficient) way to do this?

Comment: Regarding "What am I doing wrong here", could you be **more clear** about what you're trying to do. The second snippet has lots of syntax errors and doesn't appear to be meaningful. Re "most efficient" and "best", even for some well-defined goal those judgements depend on a lot of things. You could start by defining your criteria. Very explicitly.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::bind`?

Comment: @T.C. In C++11 `bind` only needs to be used in a couple corner cases, and in C++14 even in those cases the binding problem can be solved using lambdas.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf he's looking for a way to curry this function at runtime. The question is pretty clear.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, It was a missing comma.

Comment: @SU3 I guess you're in STL's "never use `bind`" camp. I'm more ambivalent on that subject.

Comment: Anyway, if you are looking for "most efficient", stop using `std::function` unless you actually need the type erasure.

Comment: @T.C. I'm in the camp "use the more powerful feature with more transparent syntax" :)

Comment: @SU3 I think [there are good use cases for each](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4171.html#appendix.bind_vs_lambda) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11, `std::bind` is essentially obsolete with the introduction of [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).
Here's an example of binding using a lambda.

```
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main() {
  auto add2 = [](int a){ return add(a,2); };

  std::cout << add2(3) << std::endl; // prints 5
}
```

For reference concerning preference of lambdas over `std::bind` one can read *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers, Item 32. In C++11 it's not possible to move capture with a lambda, and this behavior can only be emulated with `std::bind`. With introduction of init capture for lambdas in C++14, even that corner case can be nicely solved with lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

No no no.
This is what `std::bind` exists for!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>

int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main() {

    //I believe this here is just a special type of bound function.
    auto add2 = std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, 2);

    //Yup.
    std::cout << typeid(add2).name() << std::endl;
    //Here's the type of the first function.
    std::cout << typeid(add).name() << std::endl;
    //The new function.
    std::cout << add2(1) <<  std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56c0459617ba61d5

All you do is provide the function, and then the arguments you want to supply to the new function as secondary arguments to `std::bind`, and replace any "empty spaces" with `std::placeholders::_X", where X is the n-th argument number, starting from 1 for the first argument.

You can even implement closures!

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b43fe3d1651fe36

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> funcs;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        auto f = std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, i+1);
        funcs.push_back(f);
    }


    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k > -10; k = k - 2) {
        std::cout << funcs[i](k) << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

If you want to, you can also use lambdas; they tend to be cleaner as well, and you can probably avoid the nasty types of `std::bind`:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9df068bc41beb8ea

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> funcs;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        auto f = [i](int j) {return(i + j);};
        funcs.push_back(f);
    }


    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k > -10; k = k - 2) {
        std::cout << funcs[i](k) << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
return [&func2d, &inX]( double inY ){ return func2d(inX, inY); };
```

you are capturing the variables `func2d`, and `inX` by reference, which become dangling references when the function `funcYgivenX` returns.

Change the function to capture by value instead.

```
std::function< std::function< double(double) >(std::function< double(double, double) >, double) > funcYgivenX
  = [](std::function< double(double, double) > func2d, double inX)
  {
    return [func2d, inX]( double inY ){ return func2d(inX, inY); };
  };
```

When you use

```
return [func2d, inX]( double inY ){ return func2d(inX, inY); };
```

you are capturing the variables `func2d`, and `inX` by value, which continue to be valid even after the function `funcYgivenX` returns.

That's why the second version works while first version results in undefined behavior.

See working code at: http://ideone.com/X1CRGC.

Comment: The original captures two by-value function arguments by reference; said references become dangling as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @T.C., That makes sense now. He's passing both arguments to `funcYgivenX` by value.