# How to emplace a function wrapper with some arguments from local variables into container with MSVC2015?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, std

I was looking at [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30906150/673826). However I can't figure out, based on that example, why can't I bind a value of some local variable with MSVC 2015 compiler? It just throws an error while gcc 5.3 compiles it fine on msys2/mingw64. I mean like in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

using bound_add_t = decltype(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, int()));

int main() {
  std::vector<bound_add_t> vec;
  int y = 2;
  vec.emplace_back(add,std::placeholders::_1, y); // <- this causes the problem
  vec.emplace_back(add,std::placeholders::_1, 2);
  vec.emplace_back(add,std::placeholders::_1, 3);

  for (auto &b : vec)
    std::cout << b(5) << std::endl;

  return 0;   
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'std::_Binder &,int>::_Binder(std::_Binder &,int> &&)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'int' to 'int &&'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0 655

Is it a known issue tracked somewhere? I'm not even sure what is the underlying problem here. Is there a workaround?

In my use case, I'm missing one argument that becomes available later, so I'd want to have a vector with a wrapped function ready just like in that example.

**Update**

Is it a C++14 thing? I was poking around on http://ideone.com/Zi1Yht . While there is no MSVC, only compiler marked as C++14 was able to compile it.

**Update 2**

I tried

```
std::vector<std::function<int(int)> > vec;
vec.emplace_back(add, std::placeholders::_1, y);
```

if that was implied, I get

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'std::function::function(std::function &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__cdecl &)(int,int)' to 'std::allocator_arg_t'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0 655

Comment: Why not use `std::function<int(int)>` ?

Comment: The return type of `std::bind` is unspecified. and might be different for `std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, int())` and `std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, y)`.

Comment: For update2: with `vec.push_back(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, y));`

Comment: This certainly is the answer! Although I'm curious what prevents MSVC from compiling the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `std::bind` is **unspecified**.

The required constructor is the copy constructor or the move constructor.

Construct it from the arguments (function, placeholders, ...) you give is unspecified and may work for specific implementation but is not portable.

As a workaround, you may do

```
std::vector<std::function<int(int)> > vec;
int y = 2;

vec.push_back(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, y));
vec.push_back(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, 2));
vec.push_back(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

MSVC is in its right in rejecting this code. `int()` is a temporary and therefore corresponding `Args&&...` parameter is deduced as `int&&`. So the constructor of the result type of `bind` can take `int&&` as the last parameter, and `y` is not an rvalue so compilation fails.

This is not a bug in other compilers, because the result of `bind` is unspecified.

If you don't want to fall back to `std::function` you can enforce the type of the last parameter to be `const int&`:

```
using bound_add_t = decltype(std::bind(add, std::placeholders::_1, std::declval<const int&>()));
```

Comment: Awesome! I never came across `declval` before. Are there any benefits using this in place of the approach with `std::function`? With `emplace_back`, the expression looks more compact. I mean I'm confused by "fall back".

Comment: @mlt probably there's some performance gain, but it's better to measure it. Also with `std::function` you can pass anything accepting `int` and returning `int`, and this approach restricts the vector contents to be results of a very specific `bind` call. Whether it's good or bad depends on your requirements.